# How do you pass a Dynamo DB table name into an AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Okay, so I'm trying to send a Dynamo DB table name in as a parameter.   I've got the following Lambda defined:

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const DOC = require('dynamodb-doc');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: 'eu-west-1' });

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

// Set local variables to passed in variables 
var dynamoDBReadFromTableName = event.dynamoDBReadFromTableName;
var dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue = event.dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue;
var dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName = event.dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName;

// Read MCP SKU data from MCPSKU-CustomsPartKey
// Create the Parameters that are used by the GET call
let dynamoDBTableReadFromParameters = {
    TableName: dynamoDBReadFromTableName,
    Key: {
        dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName: dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue
    },
    AttributesToGet: [
        'CustomsPartKey',
        'EffectiveDateCountryOfOrigin',
        'ItemWeightLbs'
    ],
};
//Use the GET call  to read the MCP SKU data
docClient.get(dynamoDBTableReadFromParameters, function(err, dataReadFromDynamoDbtable) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(dataReadFromDynamoDbtable)
        }
    });
};
```

I tested this without passing in the AWS Dynamo DB table name - i.e. `dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName` and had 
    `"footer": dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue`
with foobar being an actually Dynamo DB name, and it works just dandy.

When I attempt to replace the Dynamo DB name with a parameter (with the same/correct name), I get the following error:

```
START RequestId: 835fa87b-fdde-11e6-9b5d-a35457d4e835 Version: $LATEST
2017-02-28T17:51:21.575Z    835fa87b-fdde-11e6-9b5d-a35457d4e835    { [ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema]
  message: 'The provided key element does not match the schema',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: Tue Feb 28 2017 17:51:21 GMT+0000 (UTC),
  requestId: 'T37SQIF62TFUFCQUMJM7DL4AJBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0 } 'ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:43:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:671:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-  sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)'
END RequestId: 835fa87b-fdde-11e6-9b5d-a35457d4e835
REPORT RequestId: 835fa87b-fdde-11e6-9b5d-a35457d4e835  Duration: 236.73 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms     Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB
```

Anyone have an idea?  Does AWS Lambda's somehow not let table names get passed in?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "AWS Lambda not letting table names get passed in". You need to start by debugging your code. At the very least add a line to log what the value of `dynamoDBReadFromTableName` is. I'm guessing you are doing something wrong when you call the Lambda function so that the `event.dynamoDBReadFromTableName` value isn't being populated. Are you invoking the Lambda function directly or using API Gateway?

Comment: How foolish of me, I did check those passed in values in a later version:      console.log('dynamoDBReadFromTableName = '+dynamoDBReadFromTableName);
    console.log('dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName = '+dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName);
    console.log('dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue = '+dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue);                                                         and the values came back fine.

Comment: I just tried using the ARN number instead of the AWS Dynamo Table name and the resulting validation error was: at 'tableName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+]
  message: '1 validation error detected:  <Arn number here yada yada yadda>. at \'tableName\' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+',
  code: 'ValidationException',

Comment: Ah.....I'm a basically a boob.   I figured it out.  (1) The table passing wasn't failing, the assignment of the Primary Ket name to the Primary Key Value was. (2)   I fixed it by using     var key = {};
    key[dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName] = dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue;

Answer (score 0):

Ah.....I'm a basically a boob. I figured it out. 
(1) The table passing wasn't failing, the assignment of the Primary Ket name to the Primary Key Value was. 
(2) I fixed it by using 
    var key = {}; 
    key[dynamoDBTablePrimaryKeyName] = dynamoDBReadFromPrimaryKeyValue;